# Correct input values of strtotime

Tags: php, date, format, strtotime

I want to convert a date by the following statement

```
$date=date('d M Y, H:m',strtotime($date));
```

It printed out `09 Sep 2012, 11:09` when I tried various values of $date:

```
11:00 AM Sunday, 09 Sep 2012
Sunday 09 Sep 2012, 11:00 AM
09 Sep 2012 11:00 AM
```

What date format does the `strtotime()` function need? It seems to me at least one of them meets the "English textual datetime description" condition.

Comment: I've added the "php" tag to your question. If you weren't asking about PHP, please update the tags.

Comment: Right, PHP should have been there, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only way to go is to sort the elements in proper order by regular expressions and then replace the month name by corresponding number. Such a string strtotime will manage.
Note: I'm talking about PHP 5.2x

EDIT: I found the reason, why strtotime "wasn't working" was that I made a typo in the date formating string, there should be 'd M Y, H:i'

Answer (score 3):

Valid formats for `strtotime` are detailed [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Answer (score 0):

From this site (http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/4/5/2)

Be wary of dates such as this one: August 25, 2003, 10:26am. Although this may look perfectly well-formed, strtotime() is not able to handle it because it has commas in there - yes, they make it much more readable for us, but strtotime() gets confused handling them. If you have dates with commas in, be sure to strip them out using str_replace().

How to deal with strtotime() -> http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp